# "IsLoading" is always true when using axios-auth-refresh with react-query

Tags: reactjs, axios, access-token, react-query

So if the Function that calls the refresh authorization fails, React-query `isLoading` will always be true.

Here is my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import createAuthRefreshInterceptor from "axios-auth-refresh";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URI,
  withCredentials: true,
});

createAuthRefreshInterceptor(axiosInstance, (failedRequest) =>
  axiosInstance.get("/auth/access-token").then((res) => {
    return Promise.resolve();
  })
);

export const getData = async (url: string) => {
  return await axiosInstance.get(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URI + url);
};``
```

And this is how I use it using react-query

```
const { data: userData, isLoading,isError } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["auth"],
    queryFn: () => getData("/users/me"),
});
```

If I console log `isLoading`, it will be always true even tho `isError` is true, so the `isLoading` should be false.

Comment: Does it ever finish the request in networks panel in dev tools?

Comment: are you saying that `isLoading` is true _and_ `isError` is true at the same time? Because that's technically impossible, as they are both derived flags from the same state, and a query can only be in one state at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/3975 will help you understand the root cause

Comment: This has nothing to do with what I'm asking